# How to use flot with jQuery in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, flot

I am trying to learn how to use [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/), and I think your example is a very nice, simple, very understandable code, so I have been trying to implement it, but here is my code in the index.aspx:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("../../Home/JsonValues", function (data) {
        alert('json: ' + data + ' ...');
        var plotarea = $("#plot_area");
        $.plot(plotarea, data);
        //$.plot(plotarea,[ [[0, 0], [1, 1]] ]);
    });
});
```

And here is the code in the HomeController:

```
public ActionResult JsonValues()
{
    //string s = "[ [[0, 0], [1, 1]] ]";
    //return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("[[0, 0], [1, 1]]");
    return Json("[" + sb.ToString() + "]", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

All I am getting is an empty graph, although when alerting in the index. I get the perfect formatted JSON data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would advise you to avoid creating JSON by hand in your controller. Try this instead:

```
public ActionResult JsonValues()
{
    return Json(
        new[] { new[] { 0, 0 }, new[] { 1, 1 } }, 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in the view:

```
<div id="plot_area" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('../../Home/JsonValues', function (data) {
        $.plot($('#plot_area'), [data]);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am also trying to use json in flot, but in vb.net/asp.net. I have a dataset that then is serialized into a JSON string. How can I take this string and put it into a flot graph?